# Mysql SELECT display only 1 result instead of multiple from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I try to make one SQL request where I get all data from multiple tables. Problem start when one user have for example more "enforcement".  But first lets look on code:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email, c.process, c.search_work, c.note,
               MAX(CASE WHEN cl.languageID = 1 THEN cl.skill ELSE '-' END)AS 'en',
               MAX(CASE WHEN cl.languageID = 2 THEN cl.skill ELSE '-' END)AS 'ge',
               ce.enforcement       
        FROM candidates AS c
        LEFT JOIN candidates_language AS cl ON c.id = cl.candidates_id
        LEFT JOIN candidates_enforcement as ce on c.id = ce.candidates_id
        GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email
```

As you can see from here I search above multiple tables with using foreign key on candidates ID.

For this purpouse here is how 2 tables looks like:

```
candidates

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |   id   |     firstname    |      surname       |        email        |
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |   22   |      John        |        Doe         |    john@doe.com     |
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |   23   |      Peter       |       Miller       |    doe@john.com     |
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

candidates_enforcement

```
        --------------------------------------------------
        |   id   |   candidates_id  |    enforcement     |
        --------------------------------------------------
        |    1   |        22        |       Advocate     |
        --------------------------------------------------
        |    2   |        22        |      Programmer    |
        --------------------------------------------------
        |    3   |        23        |       IT Admin     |
        --------------------------------------------------
```

candidates_id = foreign key from candidates. With my SQL request above result should looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |     firstname    |      surname       |        email        | enforcement
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 22 |      John        |        Doe         |    john@doe.com     | Advocate, Programmer |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 23 |      Peter       |       Miller       |    doe@john.com     | IT Admin  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unfortunately it display me ALWAYS only 1 result from "enforcement". So for cancidate with id 22 it is  Advocate not Advocate, Programmer
Is there a chance someone can help me to find a way how to fix this?
Thanks

p.s. Working demo on FIDDLE
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25b1b/1

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hi thanks for comment, my question was edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GROUP_CONCAT like this:

```
SELECT
    candidates.id,
    candidates.firstname,
    candidates.surname,
    candidates.email,
    group_concat(DISTINCT candidates_enforcement.enforcement)
FROM
    candidates
    LEFT JOIN candidates_enforcement
        ON candidates.id = candidates_enforcement.candidates_id
GROUP BY
    candidates.id,
    candidates.firstname,
    candidates.surname,
    candidates.email
```

Reference:

- [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Hi Arion, looks you lead me right way, how ever this display duplicate values if I am right.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25b1b/2

Comment: @Andurit : I updated the answer. I think you can add DISTINCT. And then it will not return duplicates

Comment: Dear Arion, YOU ARE RIGHT!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group_Concat with the Distinct option

```
SELECT c.id,c.firstname,c.surname,c.email,group_concat(distinct ce.enforcement)
FROM candidates c
LEFT JOIN candidates_enforcement ce
ON c.id=ce.candidates_id
GROUP BY c.id,c.firstname,c.surname,c.email
```

The distinct option will help you remove off the redundant values.

Comment: Hi @Venkata Krishna, you are right how ever Arion was a bit faster so I mark his question as correct. Giving you thumb up for this.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want both enforcement to show up when a person has two enforcement. The problem here is you are `LEFT` joining the candidates_enforcement table to candidate table. 
`LEFT` join does is get the tuples from candidate table and joins the corresponding tuples from candidates_enforcement. There is only one tuple for candidate in candidate table. So it only shows up one time whether candidates_enforcement has many tuples for that particular candidate or not.
 To correct this do a `RIGHT JOIN`. Or you can do the same `LEFT JOIN`, with tables swapped.

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email,ce.enforcement
FROM candidates AS c
RIGHT JOIN candidates_enforcement as ce on c.id = ce.candidates_id
```

Comment: Hi Paarandika, you understand it right, but looks dispite this I miss something becuase it doesnt work for me correctly, can you provide some demo?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25b1b/7